# Unable to Call Main Project Form

Tags: vb.net

I have two projects
1. Project1
2. Project2
I have add Project2 into Project1. Also Add Reference of Project2 into Project1.

Problem is that When I open Project2.Form1. (which I have recently added to Project1) and Try to following code:

Dim frm as New **Project1.Form1**

in the above statement my Project1 is not displaying... in the list which usually appears when we use this command...
So If I type Project1.Form1 vb gives me error... to generate

Please tell... what is happening... 
Please explain where is the problem.....  please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the form to show up:

```
Dim frm as New Project1.Form1
frm.show()
```

Comment: What list? In the intelisense?